# UICollectionView remove whitespace/header iOS11

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, ios11

I have a UICollection view which looks like this (see two purple and blue borders):

[image: UICollectionView with issue]

On iOS 10 there is no header/whitespace, but on iOS11 there is. I've tried everything mentioned here: [How can I enable/disable section headers in UICollectionView programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558772/how-can-i-enable-disable-section-headers-in-uicollectionview-programmatically)

And my code currently looks like this:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    autocompleteLayout = [[SQLProAutocompleteFlowLayout alloc] init];
    autocompleteLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSizeZero;

    autocompleteCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero
                                                    collectionViewLayout: autocompleteLayout];

    autocompleteCollectionView.insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea = NO;

    [self.view addSubview: autocompleteCollectionView];

    // removed layout code (leftAnchor, rightAnchor, topAnchor, bottomAnchor).

    autocompleteCollectionView.delegate = self;
    autocompleteCollectionView.dataSource = self;

    // Removed nib register code

    self.view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    self.view.layer.borderWidth = 1;

    autocompleteCollectionView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
    autocompleteCollectionView.layer.borderWidth = 2;
}

- (CGSize) collectionView: (UICollectionView *) collectionView
                   layout: (UICollectionViewLayout *) collectionViewLayout
referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return CGSizeZero;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
referenceSizeForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return CGSizeZero;
}
```

And my FlowLayout looks like this:

```
- (void) setupLayout
{
    self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
    self.minimumLineSpacing      = 0;
    self.scrollDirection         = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;
} // End of setupLayout

- (void) prepareLayout
{
    [super setItemSize: [self itemSize]];
    [super setSectionInset: [self sectionInset]];
    self.minimumLineSpacing = 0;

    [super prepareLayout];
} // End of prepareLayout

- (CGFloat) itemWidth
{
    return self.collectionView.frame.size.width;
}

- (CGSize) itemSize
{
    CGSize result = CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.frame.size.width,
                               rowHeight);

    return result;
}

- (void) setItemSize:(CGSize)itemSize
{
    self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.frame.size.width,
                               rowHeight);
}

- (CGPoint) targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:(CGPoint)proposedContentOffset
{
    return CGPointZero;
}
```

I have also verified that the UICollectionView's contentInset is zero'd out.

What am I missing? Why does my UICollectionView still have whitespace?

Comment: try to disable viewcontroller's Adjust scrollview insets . or disable navigationbar's translucent property .    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];

Comment: OP didn't say that it's in its own view controller.

Comment: @KKRocks just tried both. No luck (its not in a navigation controller, but gave it a shot). NRitH -- it is contained in a UIViewController.

Comment: try to set inset of collectionview  [collectionView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

Comment: @kkrocks thanks, but no difference.

Comment: try this may help this also :  [collectionView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-20, 0, 0, 0)];

Comment: @KKRocks that does do it... but it also makes me feel dirty!

Comment: yes but we cant help deeply without debug your code . so you can use this solution until you not getting proper solution.

Comment: @KKRocks appreciate the help! Thanks.

Comment: or try this also - (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(-20, 5, 5, 5);
}

Comment: The delegate method does seem to make any difference. I'll stick with the -20 offset until I can figure out the underlying reasoning. Thanks again!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In iOS 11, there have been some changes to UIScrollView.

Try setting the [contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/2902261-contentinsetadjustmentbehavior) property

```
collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;
```

Comment: If you are supporting iOS < 11:


`if #available(iOS 11.0, *)
        {
            collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior.never
        }`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
    - (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
        return 0;
    }

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0;
}


- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
   return UIEdgeInsetsMake(-25,0,0,0);  // top, left, bottom, right
}
```

Comment: Thanks, gave it a shot but no change.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Screenshot is provided in the question. using `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` results in the same as the original screenshot.

Comment: where your getting space top of the collectionview?

Comment: try adding those delegates methods also

Comment: They want solution for objective C not swift .

Comment: Language does not really matter. Easy enough to convert between the two. Unfortunately adding those methods made no difference to the whitespace.

Comment: try Changing top Inset to Minus as i updated Now ! Are u sure those methods are getting called ??